# Can Anyone Tell which package is used here

Tags: sectioning, packages

I want to create something like this. Can anyone tell which packages are used here?

[image]

Comment: For which element? The heading, the list, …? And are you sure, that a package has been used and not something handmade? There are several classes/packages, that provide multiple choice questions and answers, e.g., `exam`, `multiple-choice` …

Comment: You can create this by OpTeX, for example:).

Comment: To have 4 or more columns in parallel, see e.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol and related, see categories mentioned there.

Comment: thanks!! i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt (If anyone can tell me how to move the horizontal rule up a little to make it adjacent to the colorbox, I would be grateful. The crucial point is the precise distance between the rule and the colorbox.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem,xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_left_header_box
\box_new:N \l_right_header_box
\box_new:N \l_header_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_left_header_box {
  \vbox:n {
    \hbox:n {\sffamily Answers}
    \hbox:n {\sffamily and~ Hints}
    }
  }
\hbox_set:Nn \l_right_header_box
  {\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\sffamily Multiple~Choice~Questions}}
\vbox_set:Nn \l_header_box {
    \hbox_to_wd:nn
      {\linewidth}
      {\box_use:N \l_left_header_box \hfil \box_use:N \l_right_header_box}
    \hbox:n { \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} }
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment {answers} { +b }
  { \box_use:N \l_header_box
    \begin{multicols}{4}
      \begin{enumerate}
        [label = \textbf{\arabic*.}, nosep
         ] #1}
  { \end{enumerate} \end{multicols} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{answers}
  \item (d)
  \item (d)
  \item (b)
  \item (b)
  \item (a), (b) and (d)
  \item (c)
  \item (c)
  \item (c)
  \item (b) and (d)
  \item (c) and (d)
  \item (b)
  \item (a)
  \item (a)
  \item (d)
  \item (a)
  \item (a)
  \item (c) and (d)
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```